# Read dataframe in loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have multiple data frame as below having same format.

```
'17509_10842_10842_40005'
'17509_10842_10842_40006'
'17509_10842_10842_40007'
'17533_10842_10842_40001'
'17540_10842_10842_40001'

s <- setNames(split(Data, Data$ID), paste0(unique(Data$ID)))
list2env(s, globalenv())
```

These data frame are generated from one large in data set (please refer to below for large data set example) which I have splitted using unique values available in column ID

```
Data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID  End_Date    Value
17509_10842_10842_40005 5/22/2016   0.99
17509_10842_10842_40005 5/29/2016   0.96
17509_10842_10842_40005 6/5/2016    0.98
17509_10842_10842_40005 6/12/2016   0.87
17509_10842_10842_40005 6/19/2016   0.95
17509_10842_10842_40005 6/26/2016   0.91
17509_10842_10842_40005 7/3/2016    0.96
17509_10842_10842_40005 7/10/2016   0.92
17509_10842_10842_40005 7/17/2016   0.9
17509_10842_10842_40006 5/22/2016   0.91
17509_10842_10842_40006 5/29/2016   0.96
17509_10842_10842_40006 6/5/2016    0.95
17509_10842_10842_40006 6/12/2016   0.87
17509_10842_10842_40006 6/19/2016   0.99
17509_10842_10842_40006 6/26/2016   0.95
17509_10842_10842_40006 7/3/2016    0.99
17509_10842_10842_40006 7/10/2016   0.93
17509_10842_10842_40006 7/17/2016   0.94
17509_10842_10842_40007 5/22/2016   0.99
17509_10842_10842_40007 5/29/2016   0.96
17509_10842_10842_40007 6/5/2016    0.98
17509_10842_10842_40007 6/12/2016   0.87
17509_10842_10842_40007 6/19/2016   0.95
17509_10842_10842_40007 6/26/2016   0.91
17509_10842_10842_40007 7/3/2016    0.96
17509_10842_10842_40007 7/10/2016   0.92
17509_10842_10842_40007 7/17/2016   0.9
17533_10842_10842_40001 5/22/2016   0.91
17533_10842_10842_40001 5/29/2016   0.96
17533_10842_10842_40001 6/5/2016    0.95
17533_10842_10842_40001 6/12/2016   0.87
17533_10842_10842_40001 6/19/2016   0.99
17533_10842_10842_40001 6/26/2016   0.95
17533_10842_10842_40001 7/3/2016    0.99
17533_10842_10842_40001 7/10/2016   0.93
17533_10842_10842_40001 7/17/2016   0.94
17540_10842_10842_40001 5/22/2016   0.91
17540_10842_10842_40001 5/29/2016   0.96
17540_10842_10842_40001 6/5/2016    0.95
17540_10842_10842_40001 6/12/2016   0.87
17540_10842_10842_40001 6/19/2016   0.99
17540_10842_10842_40001 6/26/2016   0.95
17540_10842_10842_40001 7/3/2016    0.99
17540_10842_10842_40001 7/10/2016   0.93
17540_10842_10842_40001 7/17/2016   0.94
")

> str(`17509_10842_10842_40005`)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  7 variables:
```

I want to perform same analysis on these data frame in for loop, I tried it to assign in for loop but unable to get results

```
for (i in unique(Data$ID))
{

  data1 <- as.data.frame[i]

}
```

Comment: Please provide a data example. Try `dput()`.

Comment: @LAP, I have edited my query and inserted example database. I tried to use dput() but not able to get all columns in the dataframe in loop